# How to get field value - selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to get field value (having link inside) for future use, so i want to place it under parameter.

the problem is the his class name used if 7 more fields so he isnt unique.
is there a way to get this field value using the label value above this field (called "Get direct link")?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Get direct link:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="cursor: auto;
value="http://ds2.dev.polebeary.com/api/download/1521723231257836/qa_yaakov_tevel.dmg" readonly="">
</div>"
```

[need the link (who can be change of course..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuB5o.jpg)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is XPath. Find this element by using following XPath expression.

```
//div[@class="form-group"][label[text()="Get direct link:"]]/input
```

Means: Select input field which is in a div. That div has an attribute class = "form-group" and at least have a child with name label, and that label has text  "Get direct link:" in it.
For C# syntax
if you are using IWebDriver:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class="form-group"][label[text()="Get direct link:"]]/input"));
```

if you are using WebDriverWait:

```
var element = waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@class="form-group"][label[text()="Get direct link:"]]/input")));
```

Comment: Zeeshan, ive tried this as you said- 
var pathToLinkGeneral = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-control'][label[text()='Get direct link:']]/input"));
                    Console.WriteLine(pathToLinkGeneral);

but still i got error-
Message: Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='form-control'][label[text()='Get direct link:']]/input"}

Comment: @YaakovTevel Please change class="form-control" to class="form-group" in xpath. It should work. I have edited the answer as well. Thanks